# Selenium python : get specific child using parent

Tags: python, selenium

i'm trying to find a specific sub element for a list of parent, but i have a problem:
the full xpath works, but when i try to separate it into parent => child, it can't find the correct location(that's the error message)

I tried using:

'//div/div[1]/button/div/div/div/div[1]/h2 => it works but don't start from the parent so it's not what i want

'/div/div[1]/button/div/div/div/div[1]/h2' => doesn't work

'.//div/div[1]/button/div/div/div/div[1]/h2 => doesn't work

'./div/div[1]/button/div/div/div/div[1]/h2 => doesn't work

It's probably due to the parent element, but i don't understand why ..
exemple of one element of the parents list :
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="b01fcfc57a8f3d55ad083363c31fa4c3", element="cf495e96-8be5-425e-b404-b5449f694bab")>

```
self.driver.get(self.shop_link + page_link)

    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[1]/section/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/button/div/div/div/div[1]/h2')))
    elements = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[1]/section/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div')

    for element in elements:
        print(element)
        filter_name = element.find_element(By.XPATH, './/button/div/div/div/div[1]/h2')
        print(filter_name.text)

    '/html/body/div/div[1]/section/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[12]/div/div[1]/button/div/div/div/div[1]/h2'  # full xpath
    # =>
    '/html/body/div/div[1]/section/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div    /div/div[1]/button/div/div/div/div[1]/h2'   # xpath after removing the changing variable
```

error message :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//button/div/div/div/div[1]/h2"}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help !

Comment: can you share a link to the page you working on or at least the entire XML of it?

Comment: yes for sure:

https://www.lowes.ca/dept/art-wall-decor-home-decor-furniture-a28?display=100&sort=score%3Adesc&page=1


What i need are the filters on the left of the page (parent), then i want to check the name of this filter (the child)

I works like that because after checking the name i want to use again the parent to do other stuff

Comment: What exactly do you mean by parent and what is child there? parent is type or color or shape while child is a specific option like canvas (type) or green (color) etc?

Comment: Inside what parent you want to do what? how you going to specify a parent and a child? I can't see that from your code...

Comment: Here a list of parents : 
elements = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[1]/section/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div')

Then for each parent i try to find the child using the parent (element.find...) with element the parent
    for element in elements:
        filter_name = element.find_element(By.XPATH, './/button/div/div/div/div[1]/h2')

Answer (score 0):

The following code is not ideal, just to show how it works. But it works.
Here I'm selecting "Canvas" option from "Type" filters.

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")


webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
url = 'https://www.lowes.ca/dept/art-wall-decor-home-decor-furniture-a28?display=100'
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@id,'search-facet')]")))
time.sleep(6)
blocks = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@id,'search-facet')]")))
blocks[0].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//label[contains(@title,'Canvas')]").click()
```

You need to learn how to create effective locators

Comment: ty for your help ! 
I changed the code a bit and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

it is failed to find subelement for the first element, but the remaining work well,

```
from clicknium import clicknium as cc

if not cc.chrome.extension.is_installed():
    cc.chrome.extension.install_or_update()
tab = cc.chrome.open("https://www.lowes.ca/dept/art-wall-decor-home-decor-furniture-a28?display=100")
elements = tab.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/section/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div')

for element in elements:
    print(element.get_text())
    filter_name = element.find_element_by_xpath('.//button/div/div/div/div[1]/h2')
    if filter_name != None:
        print(filter_name.get_text())
    else:
        print("none")
```